# Photoshop Actions, save multiple file names, less specific folder

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5, photoshop-action

I made a photoshop action to save a series of images into a particular resolution and file name. 6 images total, unfortunately the "save" function to be used within Action stores a hardpath to the saving location, this makes the action no good for a different computer.

The batch function is also too bad and not a solution (like everything on google might have you believe), because it can't save 6 files with different naming conventions (like the "save" function can).

I am guessing I need to implement somekind of javascript function for CS5? Not sure yet.

for the record, I am saving the 6 icon files that iOS apps need. These use different resolutions and different names.